# Conditional variables depending on whether Matlab or Octave is running the code

Tags: matlab, octave

I have written some code for Matlab/Octave. Basically, they have the same syntax and everything, but, for example, they have different functions for optimization (`linprog`/`glpk`,`quadprog`/`qp`).

I want to run the same code in both Matlab and Octave and this code suffers from needing different functions in each environment.
Until now, I have a variable that tells the programm whether it is running on Matlab or on Octave, but I always have to set this variable manually.

Is there a way that a program can recognise in which environment it runs? So, I want a statement to set the variable `x=1`, if it is running on Octave and `x=0` if it is running on Matlab.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question that is appropriate here...

Comment: I am sure. It's not.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this question is in the wrong forum. My first guess would be that the answer depends on the OS, but I did most of my programming under DOS, so probably shouldn't comment. Migrate to SO? I will flag a moderator.

Comment: Ideally one should ask this at the MatLab or GNU Octave mailing lists/fora. But this is clearly off-topic. I'll migrate to SuperUser. As Jyrki pointed out, it may require making system calls and what not.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know where to post it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check whether Octave’s built-in variable `OCTAVE_VERSION` is set.